# PHP preg_replace: remove all 2 char words & 3 char ending in s

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for being dumb when it comes to RegEx, but I'm just having an issue with this:

`$search=trim(preg_replace('@ [a-z]{1,2}s? @',' ',' '.$search.' '));`

As far as I can see, that should remove all lowercase 2 character words, and any lowercase 3 characters words ending in "s".

The part that doesn't work is that it does not remove lowercase 3 character words ending in "s".

Any ideas?

Thanks.

See example:
http://codepad.org/yUpyn8KU

Comment: In: `magic to feel in ses she` Out: `magic feel ses she`

Comment: The space that appears after `"in"` is the same space that appears before `"ses"`. The regex engine replaces `" in "` but it resumes searching after the space, not before it.

Comment: Interesting... so what's the best option for fixing that?

Comment: Thanks AlphaMale for your help. I already figured the answer out by combining my code with the word boundary usage suggested by Kevin.

Comment: You should accept the appropriate answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$search=trim(preg_replace('/\b([a-z]{1,2}|[a-z]{2}s)\b/',' ',' '.$search.' '));
```

Comment: It sort-of works, except there are lots of extra spaces left over (http://codepad.org/vvlAG8rG). Also, what does the `\b` part do?

Comment: I added the word boundary to my own code, then removed the double spaces and that works. So +1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sanitize a search string, you could explode it:

```
$search_items = explode(' ', $search);
$search = ' ';
foreach ($search_items AS $search_item) {
  $search_item = trim($search_item);
  if (strlen($search_item) > 3 || (strlen($search_item) == 3 && substr($search_item,-1) != 's') {
    $search .= $search_item . ' ';
  }
}
```

With regex, I would try

```
$search=trim(preg_replace('@(\s)(\s+)?([a-z]{1,2}s?)(\s)@','$1',' '.$search.' '));
```

`(\s)` at the beginning and the end look for whitespace. Second pair of parentheses looks for additional whitespaces that may be removed. If pattern is found, only the very first space is left in string.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually I'm trying to avoid this. It would be easy to explode it and check each token, but that is not particularly efficient it seems to me.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it.

```
$search=trim(preg_replace('@\b[a-z]{1,2}s?\b@','',$search));
$search=preg_replace('@\s+@',' ',$search);
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

***Here it is on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/YgIWjrlp)***

```
<?php 
 $string = "ver ae as ads dase asda frasad ae aes ads ad hag hags";
 $result = trim(preg_replace('/\b([a-z]{1,2}|[a-z]{2}s)\b/',' ',' '.$string.' '));
 echo $trim = preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',$result);
?>
```

***Here it is on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/YgIWjrlp)***

Hope this helps.